# try to create an array in js then send to controller

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Im try to send an array to my controller in Codeigniter,To then be able to use this array in my controller, but gettting a problem in the creation the `array` repeat the line 
[image]

here my js function

```
 function get_array(){
   var datos = [];
   row = {};
  $("#tbl_esctructura tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var item = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
     row["item"] = item;
     row["cantidad"] = cantidad;
     datos.push(row); // you push it to the array
  });

    datos =  JSON.stringify(datos);
}
```

here my controller

```
public function data_from_array(){
    $data   =  array($this->input->post('datos', TRUE));

    foreach ($data as $row) {

        echo $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your code like that.

```
 function get_array(){
   var datos = [];
  $("#tbl_esctructura tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var row = {};
    var item = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var cantidad = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
     row.item = item;
     row.cantidad = cantidad;
     datos.push(row); // you push it to the array
  });

    datos =  JSON.stringify(datos);
}
```